# My phone is not connecting to the cell network (No Service)

Tags: cellular-radio

I have an Android KitKat based phone. For over a week the phone is getting poor (at times) or no reception but the WiFi and bluetooth is working.

There is a cross near where the range is shown and I get "No Service" in the notification. 
This screenshot summarizes my situation:

[image]

Here is a list of things I tried to do, but did not solve the problem:

1. Get a new duplicate sim card.
2. Use a working SIM card from a different service provider.
3. Switch to 2G mode and back.
4. Reset my phone.
5. Completely flash the stock ROM again.
6. Flash several modems from XDA.

**Edit:** Even if it is a hardware issue, is it possible to get some debug information? Like for example, somewhere in the kernel logs, it should be possible to know for sure what is happening, right? What and were to look for this information?

**Edit2:** [Device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132863/my-phone-is-not-connecting-to-the-cell-network-no-service#comment167282_132863) is Lenovo P780, ROW (not chinese) per OP clarification

Comment: Rooted? Radio logs might help:`adb logcat -b radio -v time -d > logcat_radio.log` possibly kernel logs would also help. From a root shell: `dmesg > dmesg.txt`

Comment: @beeshyams When I flash, there are many different partitions listed. (Eg: PRELOADER, MBR, EBR,1 RECOVERY etc.) Which one of this would contain the modem? The IMEI is correct. Will IMEI be lost when I flash a new modem?

Comment: @beeshyams Sorry I forgot about it. It is a Lenovo P780, ROW (not chinese) with baseband version `P780.V24`

Comment: Back up your phone and try flashing modems from here http://forum.xda-developers.com/lenovo-p780/general/how-modems-t2757923,

Comment: This supports possible modern issue http://forum.xda-developers.com/lenovo-p780/development/p780-row-s226-flash-flashtool-t2909202/page4

Comment: This seems to be latest ROM for your device but you did not mention full details of your device (package details), so please recheck http://www.needrom.com/download/p780-android-4-4-2/

Comment: @beeshyams What do you mean by recheck? Did you mean 'reflash'? I tried the three modems and a few others specified in XDA and there is no difference. What do you mean by package details? I flashed S228 and installed TWRP.

Comment: Ok..so that possibility ruled out.

Comment: Sniffing in the dark here, but try wiping partition cache? I don't know if it makes a difference if you've reset your phone but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Reset Your android 
just search for recovery mode buttons combination in google for your android

then choose wipe data/cache in that option